# Why is there a difference when I use "aray+=1" and "aray = aray + 1"

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

```
import torch
import numpy as np

aray = np.arange(1, 11)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(aray)
print(f"aray: {aray}, \ntensor: {tensor}\n\n\n")

aray = 1 + aray
print(f"aray + 1: {aray}, \ntensor: {tensor}")
```

When I use `aray += 1`, the tensor variable changes too, but when I use `aray = aray + 1` it doesn't. Why?

Comment: did you use `aray + 1` or `1 + aray`?

Comment: both give the same output

Comment: In your code, when you use `aray += 1`, you're performing an in-place operation that modifies the existing NumPy array. On the other hand, when you use `aray = aray + 1`, you are creating a new NumPy array by adding 1 element-wise to the existing aray. This new array is assigned back to the aray variable. However, this operation doesn't modify the original NumPy array.

Comment: so is this tutorial wrong at 3:39:15?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_xro1bcAuA&t=11312s

Comment: Indeed, the tutorial is wrong at that point, in saying "If you use `from_numpy()`, we get a new tensor in memory" (3:39:30). Here is the correctly timestamped link for 3:39:15, by the way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_xro1bcAuA&t=13155s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Sparsh Choudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22470636/sparsh-choudhary) explained in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77007058/12131013), because you used `torch.from_numpy`, they end up referencing the same memory location. When using `+=` (i.e. `__iadd__`), the memory address stays the same (the operation is performed in-place when possible, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034672/how-do-numpys-in-place-operations-e-g-work)). But when you perform `aray = aray + 1`, you're creating a new array, so the result no longer references the original memory address (since it's a completely new array). But `tensor` is unchanged and will still point to the original memory address.

We can check this by getting the memory pointers for the numpy array and pytorch tensor (the methods for each are slightly different, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60591401/12131013)).

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

aray = np.arange(1, 11)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(aray)

print(f"aray: {aray}")
print(f"tensor: {tensor}")

print(f"aray pointer: {aray.ctypes.data}")
print(f"tensor pointer: {tensor.data_ptr()}")

print("Inplace Addition:")
aray += 1
print(f"aray: {aray}")
print(f"tensor: {tensor}")

print(f"aray pointer: {aray.ctypes.data}")
print(f"tensor pointer: {tensor.data_ptr()}")


print("Normal Addition")

aray = 1 + aray
print(f"aray: {aray}")
print(f"tensor: {tensor}")

print(f"aray pointer: {aray.ctypes.data}")
print(f"tensor pointer: {tensor.data_ptr()}")
```

Output:

```py
aray: [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
tensor: tensor([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
aray pointer: 62868976
tensor pointer: 62868976
Inplace Addition:
aray: [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
tensor: tensor([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
aray pointer: 62868976
tensor pointer: 62868976
Normal Addition
aray: [ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
tensor: tensor([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
aray pointer: 62869120
tensor pointer: 62868976
```

As you can see, after they are created, they share the same memory address, and this persists through the `+=` operation. But once you perform `aray = aray + 1`, `aray` now references a new location in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I see the source of the confusion now. In your code, when you use `aray += 1`, it indeed modifies both aray and tensor because tensor is created using `torch.from_numpy(aray)`, which means it shares its underlying data with the NumPy array `aray`. This behavior is a result of how NumPy and PyTorch handle memory management and array operations.

Here's what happens:

`aray` is a NumPy array containing integers from 1 to 10.
`tensor` is created from `aray` using `torch.from_numpy(aray)`. This means tensor shares the same underlying data with `aray`.
When you do `aray += 1`, it modifies the original NumPy array `aray` in place. Since tensor shares the same data, it also reflects the changes.

However, when you do `aray = aray + 1`, you are creating a new NumPy array that results from adding 1 to each element of the original `aray`. This new array is then assigned to the variable `aray`. This doesn't modify the original array in place, and tensor still references the old data.

If you want tensor to reflect the changes in this case, you would need to recreate it from the updated `aray`:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

aray = np.arange(1, 11)
tensor = torch.from_numpy(aray)
print(f"aray: {aray}, \ntensor: {tensor}\n\n\n")

aray = aray + 1  # Create a new array with updated values
tensor = torch.from_numpy(aray)  # Update 'tensor' to reflect the changes
print(f"aray + 1: {aray}, \ntensor: {tensor}")
```

Now, tensor will correctly reflect the changes made to `aray` using `aray = aray + 1`.

Comment: so is this tutorial wrong at 3:39:15? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_xro1bcAuA&t=11312s

Comment: Correct link for 3:39:15 is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_xro1bcAuA&t=13155s. Wrong statement is a few seconds later (3:39:30)